# Add decorator to data adapter in Select2 version 4.x

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I want to support the `MaximumInputLength` decorator for my custom Select2 [Data Adapter](https://select2.github.io/options.html#dataAdapter). In my custom data adapter, the `Utils.Decorate()` call does not do anything.

Looking at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/timkelty/ae79d180acc9d3054e02), I could call the Decorator function in the same place where I initialize `select2()`, but that seems icky and not DRY, as I want to initialize many of these Select elements.

In order to enable minimum input for ALL instances of MyDataAdapter, is it possible to decorate that adapter from the adapter itself? Is there a better way to do this?

My `select2()` call:

```
$('select').select2({
    dataAdapter: MyDataAdapter,
    minimumInputLength: 2
});
```

`MyDataAdapter` (sans dependencies):

```
define([...], function(Utils, MinimumInputLength, ArrayAdapter){

    function MyDataAdapter($element, options) {
        this.$element = $element;
        this.options = options;
        MyDataAdapter.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
    }

    Utils.Extend(MyDataAdapter, ArrayAdapter);
    Utils.Decorate(MyDataAdapter, MinimumInputLength); <-- does nothing

    MyDataAdapter.prototype.query = function(params, callback) {
        console.log('query!');
    };

    return MyDataAdapter;

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll notice in [the gist](https://gist.github.com/timkelty/ae79d180acc9d3054e02) that their call to decorate their adapter looks like

```
var dropdownAdapter = Utils.Decorate(
  Utils.Decorate(
    DropdownAdapter,
    DropdownSearch
  ),
  AttachContainer
);
```

And they later go on to use `dropdownAdapter` when initializing Select2. This is because `Utils.Decorate` *returns* the decorated class instead of decorating it in-place. You'll also notice that it does this *after* the decorator and adapters have already been created.

So instead of calling `Utils.Decorate` in the middle of your adapter, you should call it at the end. Either when you are returning the finished adapter, or right before you do.

```
define([...], function(Utils, MinimumInputLength, ArrayAdapter){    
    function MyDataAdapter($element, options) {
        this.$element = $element;
        this.options = options;
        MyDataAdapter.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
    }

    // Always extend after making the constructor
    Utils.Extend(MyDataAdapter, ArrayAdapter);

    MyDataAdapter.prototype.query = function(params, callback) {
        console.log('query!');
    };

    // Decorate after the adapter is built
    return Utils.Decorate(MyDataAdapter, MinimumInputLength);
});
```

Before your major issue was that you were not using the returned class from `Utils.Decorate`. But the other issue that you would have hit is that it just wouldn't work, which was because you were overriding the `query` method after it had been decorated.

Comment: "Either when you are returning the finished adapter, or right before you do." how would I do this right before I return, rather than returning the `Utils.Decorate()` call?

Comment: @BenjaminSmith If you wanted to assign the result to a variable, do something extra with it (or something else), and then return that variable it would work as well.

Comment: Is there a "complete" working script for this functionality? I was hoping to separate the select initialization from the decoration as well.