# Select2 custom dataAdapter without AMD

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I want to create a custom dataAdapter for select2 but the examples I see online all make use of AMD. We don't use AMD in our projects. How can I create my custom dataAdapter? A plain object that implements `current` and `query` methods is not enough.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out you can almost completely avoid the use of AMD. The following works for me with select2 version 4.0.10:

```
const ArrayAdapter = $.fn.select2.amd.require("select2/data/array");

class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    constructor($element, options)
    {
        super($element, options);
    }

    query(params, callback)
    {
        console.log("params: " + JSON.stringify(params));
    }
}

$("#my-combo-box").select2(
    {
        dataAdapter: DataAdapter
    }
);
```

You can ever go as far as accessing `$.fn.select2.amd.require._defined["select2/data/array"]` instead of invoking `amd.require()` but there is probably no point going this far :)

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for ages. Thank you! So much cleaner than anything else I've seen.

Comment: @NickBrunt hey buddy could you share a simple example of how you accomplished this? I'm trying to customize the dropdown content with the Dropdown decorator, but having hard times with it :(. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Select2 has a built-in AMD loader that it uses for loading plugins and adapters, so you would need to use that to build out your custom data adapter.

You can find examples of customized data adapters at [Add decorator to data adapter in Select2 version 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30631024/359284#30631849)

Instead of calling `define` directly, you would need to use the method provided by Select2 in `jQuery.fn.select2.amd`. So something like

```
define('something/awesome', ['select2/data/array', function (ArrayAdapter) {
  // Use the array adapter
}]);
```

would become

```
jQuery.fn.select2.amd.define('something/awesome', ['select2/data/array', function (ArrayAdapter) {
  // Use the array adapter
}]);
```